# statsmodels adfuller is not working right with 21 days window

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I am using the below code to check for stationarity on a rolling basis. I am checking for the p value. Freakishly the code is working fine on various rolling windows(even 20 & 22) but not on 21 days rolling window.  Whereas all other windows expectedly return a highly variable line the 21 days rolling gives a straight line. I have tried it on multiple time series.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import pandas as pd
def stationarity(x):
    return adfuller(x)[1]
x is any pandas timeseries
x.rolling(21).apply(lambda x: adfuller(x)[1]).plot()
```

Comment: That is most likely a special feature of your data. You need to provide your data or show a plot of your data. Unit root test will not have much power in short time series like this.